# How to pull one day old data from remote server to local server?

Tags: linux, find, rsync, scp

From what I have searched till now I only found command to **PUSH** one day old data from local server to remoteServer but what I want is to **PULL** one day old data from remoteServer to localServer.

I tried combining `find -mtime` with `rsync on remoteServer files but didn't got the result.

Comment: what do you mean by "one-day-old" data? Files with modification time during last 24 hours? Backup snapshot from yesterday? Something else?

Comment: @Jakuje yeah I meant that only with files modified time during last 24 hrs i.e `-mtime -1`

Answer (score 0):

On SuperUser there is an alternative posted by Sehe:

https://superuser.com/questions/297342/rsync-files-newer-than-1-week

```
rsync -RDa0P --files-from=<(find sourcedir/./ -mtime -7 -print0) . user@B:targetdir/
```